# Configure Minted Color XML

Tags: minted, xml

I'm using minted package for code listing, however I don't like some of the colors too much. Is it possible to configure these colors? For example, When I display the colors to view XML color, the keyword appear green which I don't want. Can somebody explain of this is possible?

I'm including the package and including the XML code:

```
\usepackage{minted}
\inputminted{xml}{codeListings/test.xml.tex}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Since `minted` uses Pygments lib resp. the pygmentize program for the hard work, this sounds more like a Pygments question. You may read the help file on pygmentize `pygmentize -h` and the lexers and styles lists `-L styles` or `-L lexers`. It is possible to write an individual appearance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me try to show your a way at LaTeX level.

First of all we must analyze the way pygmentize highlight the code and how do we get highlighted code in LaTeX.

If you have something like the following code:

```
\begin{minted}{xml}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
            xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
            version="2.5">
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <description>JAX-WS endpoint</description>
    <display-name>WSServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>WSServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WSServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CompressionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.bsiag.fleet.external.calculation.webservice.compression.CompressionFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CompressionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
\end{minted}
```

Now the contents of the environment is written to the file `\jobname.pyg`. Now pygmentize get its chance. After  running it you will have a file named `\jobname.out.pyg` with the following contents:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}, ]
\PY{c+cp}{\PYZlt{}?xml version=\PYZdq{}1.0\PYZdq{} encoding=\PYZdq{}UTF\PYZhy{}8\PYZdq{}?\PYZgt{}}
\PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}web\PYZhy{}app}   \PY{n+na}{xmlns:xsi=}\PY{l+s}{\PYZdq{}http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\PYZhy{}instance\PYZdq{}}
            \PY{n+na}{xmlns=}\PY{l+s}{\PYZdq{}http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee\PYZdq{}}
            \PY{n+na}{xmlns:web=}\PY{l+s}{\PYZdq{}http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web\PYZhy{}app\PYZus{}2\PYZus{}5.xsd\PYZdq{}}
            \PY{n+na}{xsi:schemaLocation=}\PY{l+s}{\PYZdq{}http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web\PYZhy{}app\PYZus{}2\PYZus{}5.xsd\PYZdq{}}
            \PY{n+na}{version=}\PY{l+s}{\PYZdq{}2.5\PYZdq{}}\PY{n+nt}{\PYZgt{}}
  \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}listener\PYZgt{}}
    \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}listener\PYZhy{}class\PYZgt{}}com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener\PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/listener\PYZhy{}class\PYZgt{}}
  \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/listener\PYZgt{}}
  \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}servlet\PYZgt{}}
    \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}description\PYZgt{}}JAX\PYZhy{}WS endpoint\PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/description\PYZgt{}}
    \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}display\PYZhy{}name\PYZgt{}}WSServlet\PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/display\PYZhy{}name\PYZgt{}}
    \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}servlet\PYZhy{}name\PYZgt{}}WSServlet\PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/servlet\PYZhy{}name\PYZgt{}}
    \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}servlet\PYZhy{}class\PYZgt{}}com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet\PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/servlet\PYZhy{}class\PYZgt{}}
    \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}load\PYZhy{}on\PYZhy{}startup\PYZgt{}}1\PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/load\PYZhy{}on\PYZhy{}startup\PYZgt{}}
  \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/servlet\PYZgt{}}
  \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}servlet\PYZhy{}mapping\PYZgt{}}
    \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}servlet\PYZhy{}name\PYZgt{}}WSServlet\PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/servlet\PYZhy{}name\PYZgt{}}
    \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}url\PYZhy{}pattern\PYZgt{}}/services/*\PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/url\PYZhy{}pattern\PYZgt{}}
  \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/servlet\PYZhy{}mapping\PYZgt{}}
  \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}filter\PYZgt{}}
    \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}filter\PYZhy{}name\PYZgt{}}CompressionFilter\PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/filter\PYZhy{}name\PYZgt{}}
    \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}filter\PYZhy{}class\PYZgt{}}com.bsiag.fleet.external.calculation.webservice.compression.CompressionFilter\PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/filter\PYZhy{}class\PYZgt{}}
  \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/filter\PYZgt{}}
  \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}filter\PYZhy{}mapping\PYZgt{}}
    \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}filter\PYZhy{}name\PYZgt{}}CompressionFilter\PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/filter\PYZhy{}name\PYZgt{}}
    \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}url\PYZhy{}pattern\PYZgt{}}/*\PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/url\PYZhy{}pattern\PYZgt{}}
  \PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/filter\PYZhy{}mapping\PYZgt{}}
\PY{n+nt}{\PYZlt{}/web\PYZhy{}app\PYZgt{}}
\end{Verbatim}
```

Now we see that every highlight at LaTeX-Level is done by the command `\PY` which has two mandatory arguments. The first one is the style and the second the highlighted string.

Now we need the definition of `\PY` and friends:

```
\def\PY@reset{\let\PY@it=\relax \let\PY@bf=\relax%%
    \let\PY@ul=\relax \let\PY@tc=\relax%%
    \let\PY@bc=\relax \let\PY@ff=\relax}
\def\PY@tok#1{\csname PY@tok@#1\endcsname}
\def\PY@toks#1+{\ifx\relax#1\empty\else%%
    \PY@tok{#1}\expandafter\PY@toks\fi}
\def\PY@do#1{\PY@bc{\PY@tc{\PY@ul{%%
    \PY@it{\PY@bf{\PY@ff{#1}}}}}}}
\def\PY#1#2{\PY@reset\PY@toks#1+\relax+\PY@do{#2}}
```

pygmentize also change special characters to commands to prevent any conflicts:

```
\def\PYZbs{\char`\\}
\def\PYZus{\char`\_}
\def\PYZob{\char`\{}
\def\PYZcb{\char`\}}
\def\PYZca{\char`\^}
\def\PYZam{\char`\&}
\def\PYZlt{\char`\<}
\def\PYZgt{\char`\>}
\def\PYZsh{\char`\#}
\def\PYZpc{\char`\%%}
\def\PYZdl{\char`\$}
\def\PYZti{\char`\~}
%% for compatibility with earlier versions
\def\PYZat{@}
\def\PYZlb{[}
\def\PYZrb{]}
```

Related to the commands above and the character definition the highlighting is done by:

```
\def\PY@tok@gd{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@gu{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.50,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@gt{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.25,0.82}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@gs{\let\PY@bf=\textbf}
\def\PY@tok@gr{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@cm{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@vg{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@m{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@mh{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@go{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.50,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@ge{\let\PY@it=\textit}
\def\PY@tok@vc{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@il{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@cs{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@cp{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.74,0.48,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@gi{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@gh{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@ni{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.60,0.60,0.60}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@nl{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@nn{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@no{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@na{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.49,0.56,0.16}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@nb{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@nc{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@nd{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@ne{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.82,0.25,0.23}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@nf{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@si{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@s2{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@vi{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@nt{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@nv{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@s1{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@sh{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@sc{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@sx{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@bp{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@c1{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@kc{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@c{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@mf{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@err{\def\PY@bc##1{\fcolorbox[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{1,1,1}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@kd{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@ss{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@sr{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@mo{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@kn{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@mi{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@gp{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@o{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@kr{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@s{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@kp{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@w{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.73,0.73}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@kt{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.00,0.25}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@ow{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@sb{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@k{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@se{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.13}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@sd{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
```

If you want to change something it must be done between `\makeatletter` and `makeatother` and inside `\AtBeginDocument`:

Here my test file:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\renewcommand\DeleteFile[1]{}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\def\PY@tok@c{\let\PY@it=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@cp{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{1.0,0.2,0.5}{##1}}}
\def\PY@tok@nt{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.20,0.00}{##1}}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{xml}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
            xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
            version="2.5">
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <description>JAX-WS endpoint</description>
    <display-name>WSServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>WSServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WSServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CompressionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.bsiag.fleet.external.calculation.webservice.compression.CompressionFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CompressionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not to rain on your parade but the documentation shows a way of changing the colours much easier. I would *not* recommend the above.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It's a LaTeX way -- I had never said that I recommend this way ;-) -- However you way is much better.

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust the colour scheme with the following command:

```
\usemintedstyle{name}
```

‹name› is the name of an installed colour scheme. To get a list of those, issue the following command on the command line:

```
pygmentize -L styles
```

To create your own styles, [follow the instructions in the Pygments documentation](http://pygments.org/docs/styles/).

Answer (score 0):

Update for the curious.  If you're seeking to modify just one or two stylings, the prefix is no longer `PY`, it's `PYG`, and if you want to override something for just one particular color scheme ('perldoc' as an example), you have to do something like this:

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \def\PYGperldoc@tok@kt{\let\PYGperldoc@bf=\textbf\def\PYGperldoc@tc##1{\textcolor[HTML]{00688B}{##1}}}
}
\makeatother
```

But this is some serious monkey patching and, like all monkey patches, is very brittle and prone to breaking when the package/library updates.  You have been warned.